# Cannot load image in my iPhone app

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, phonegap-plugins, sencha-architect

I use sencha touch framework with PhoneGap to create a hybrid application in iPhone,
in the device I cannot load image or audio from the internet, 
in the browser it's work.

Any help please.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Check that your phonegap config.xml allows access to the domain(s) where your media are located - see [phonegap's documentation for the Access element](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml#access).

For instance you could test by setting:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

into your config.xml - this will allow your application to connect to any URL.

Comment: it's not work, the problem when i use Ext.video i can load this video or when i use Ext.image i cannot load this image